# Overwriting .style.property value with .classList.toggle doesn't appear to work

Tags: javascript

**Question:** `.classList.toggle` adds or removes a css class from an element. It works great but I appear to have stumbled across a limitation that I hope someone can show me a way around.

When I use Javascript to set an elements style, for example `.style.backgroundColor = "red"` a following line using `classList.toggle` doesn't appear to be able to overwrite this style.

**Details:**  The code below works perfect.  By clicking the window the background color switches from red to blue.

```js
window.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
 
function myFunction(e) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("box_1")[0].classList.toggle("color_swap");
}
```

```css
.box_1 {
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;
 transition: all .5s;
}

.color_swap {
 background-color: blue;
 transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_1"></div>
```

However when I add the top line that sets the background color with Javascript the transition no longer works.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("box_1")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
 
window.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
 
function myFunction(e) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("box_1")[0].classList.toggle("color_swap");
}
```

```css
.box_1 {
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;
 transition: all .5s;
}

.color_swap {
 background-color: blue;
 transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_1"></div>
```

Is there a way around this problem?  I'd like to be able to set properties in Javascript and still use Javascript to `toggle`/`add`/`remove` classes.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.box_1` already has `background-color: red;` so you shouldn't be setting an inline style with JavaScript.

Inline styles added to an element will override styles in classes. Read the docs on Specificity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

You can use `!important` to override that.

```
.color_swap {
    background-color: blue !important;
    transition: all .5s;
}
```

Perhaps your confusion is with how styles work. Toggling a class doesn't set the style of the element, unlike a property of an object. The final style of the element ultimately depends on the specificity.

Comment: Holy smokes you are correct.  I didn't think about specificity but when I watched the code in Devtools > Elements I saw what you meant.  Thanks!